# Application works on local dev enviroment but not when deployed on server?

Tags: php, api, deployment

I created an application using flickr API + PHP. Somehow my code works in my local machine but when I deploy it onto a server it breaks.

The warning I am getting is:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/u189255383/public_html/imageGallery/imageProcess.php on line 124.

In my code, that part is `foreach($resultObj['photos']['photo'] as $photo)` just a code to process the result passed in from the function that gets the result from requesting flickr API.

I found out that it says invalid simply because nothing is in `$resultObj`, thats why it's Invalid argument, but I don't get why it's empty.

```
$url = $request . $method . $sign . $apiKey . $sign . 'text=' . urlencode($input) . $sign . $per_page . $sign . $page . $i . $sign . $format;       
$result = file_get_contents($url);
$resultObj = unserialize($result);
```

This is basically what I did before returning the result. I tried to see if anything inside `$result` but turn out that it's already empty at `$result`, meaning the `file_get_contents($url);` function isn't being executed.

Comment: flickr should be returning json not a php serialized string.... swap out unserialize with json_decode($result, true)

Comment: btw this shouldn't have work local either.

Comment: Are you sure that your live server allows you to use file_get_contents with a URL?

Comment: @Orangepill, I thought the format of  result return by flickr depends on which one you requested. http://www.flickr.com/services/api/. you have 5 options i choose the PHP one, and in there it says use Serialized PHP Response Format

PHP has a built-in serialized data structure format, using the serialize() and unserialize() functions.

Comment: @andrewsi do you mean "allow_url_fopen" ? if so then in the php.info from the live server its "ON" so i suppose yes?

Comment: @JerryLai - that's the one. Hmmmmmmmm - my only other suggestion would be to try and use a local file, and see if that makes a difference. If you can read it from a local file but not the remote one, then there's something preventing the connection.

Comment: @JerryLai Sorry for the misleading comment you are completely correct then

Comment: @andrewsi Hmmm....if upload a txt file and used "file_get_contents()" to read whats inside and echoed it out. It worked...so I guess something is preventing the connection like you mentioned.....man.....this is driving me crazy !!!

Comment: That looks like it's a server configuration issue, in that case - I'm afraid I don't know enough about it to be of help. You might want to edit your question, and hopefully someone more knowledgeable will be able to help you more!

Answer (score 0):

Try using curl. You should check if curl is installed on the remote server:

```
$url = $request . $method . $sign . $apiKey . $sign . 'text=' . urlencode($input) . $sign . $per_page . $sign . $page . $i . $sign . $format;       
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$resultObj = unserialize($result);
```

Comment: hi sorry for the late reply, I have been busy recently so yeah havn't tried your solution but i remember written something using curl and tried it before which didn't work but i will use urs again and get it a try perhaps later tonight and let you know the result. but i think its not the code's problem, its probably something to do with the host due to security reasons maybe?

Comment: Did you get any errors in apache error log or other logfiles?

Comment: Hi Richard, nop all i get is the same old message "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/u189255383/public_html/imageGallery/imageProcess.php on line 124."